# How do I remove all of the nested span tags within a span tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have innerHTML that looks like this:

```
<span class="test"> <span> </span> Hello I am here <span class="test1"> </span> </span>
```

I want to remove all of the nested span tags so that I get this:

```
<span class="test"> Hello I am here </span>
```

I have tried using .replace('', '').replace('', '') in but would have to check the last span somehow and also there could be different spans that are dynamically being made from google docs so it would be better if I could do a replace on all of the spans that is not the first or last span.

Comment: Please be clear on your question. Will the span tags have any content within them? Should those be kept? Will there be elements besides spans inside your element?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
$('.test').find('span').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test"> <span>dummy data </span> Hello I am here <span class="test1"> dummay data</span> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the outer span's `textContent` to it's own `textContent` - because reading an element's `textContent` doesn't return any markup tags intersperse with the text.

Resetting `textContent` also avoids the content of text being parsed by the HTML parser, as it would if used to set the outer element's `innerHTML` property.

```js
"use strict";
let testSpan = document.querySelector(".test");
testSpan.textContent = testSpan.textContent;
console.log( testSpan.outerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="test"><span> </span> Hello I am here <span class="test1"> </span> </span>
```

If you wanted to you could replace consecutive whitespace characters witha single space character before assigning back `textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```js
"use strict";
const elm = document.querySelector(".test");
elm.innerHTML = elm.innerText;
console.log(elm.outerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="test"><span> </span> Hello I am here <span class="test1"> </span> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use this code to get rid of any empty `span` elements.

```js
const allSpan = document.querySelectorAll("span");

allSpan.forEach(item => {
  if(item.childElementCount === 0 && item.textContent.trim().length === 0){
    item.parentElement.removeChild(item)
  }
})
```

```html
<span class="test">
  <span> </span> Hello I am here <span class="test1"> </span> 
</span>;
```

You can see the result by inspecting the code in the browser

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it mention empty span elements, just nested ones.